# Bash joining array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to join (with proper quoting and escaping) a bash array such that it gives me a string suitable for passing to `bash -c`?

**Reason**:
I want to write a function `foo`, such that when I do this:

```
foo app "hello world.txt"
```

it'll do this:

```
sudo -u myuser ENVVAR=somevalue bash -c "perl app \"hello world.txt\""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash -c` takes the first argument as the command string, and assigns the remaining arguments to positional arguments starting from `$0`. So, you don't need to quote anything, just pass the arguments:

```
function foo () {
    sudo -u myuser ENVVAR=somevalue bash -c 'perl "$0" "$@"' "$@"
}
```